# Практическое применение Enum

Tags: java, android, enum

Меня всегда волновал вопрос класса `Enum`: какие у них есть преимущества перед обычными `static final` примитивами?

И, если можно, поделитесь вашим опытом, в котором использование `Enum` было бы действительно оправданным.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252465/android-enum-vs-static-final-ints

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`enum` имеет ряд преимуществ при использовании в сравнении с `static final int`. И использовать его стоит в том случае если вам нужны эти преимущества.

Главным отличием является то что используя `enum` вы можете проверить тип данных.

Например:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static int RED = 1;
    public static int BLUE = 2;
    public static int YELLOW = 3;
    public static int GREEN = 3; // Совпадающие значения

    private int color;

    public void setColor(int color) {
        this.color = color;
    }   
}
```

При этом вы можете передать в класс любое значение `int`.

```
new SomeClass().setColor(999);
```

Следовательно, основные проблемы использования `static final int` это:

- Необходимость проверки вводимых данных.
- Нет никакой защиты от создания `static final int` переменной с дублирующимся значением.

Еще одним преимуществом `enum` является возможность перегружать методы.

```
public enum UnitConverter{
    METERS{
        @Override
        public double toMiles(final double meters){
            return meters * 0.00062137D;
        }

        @Override
        public double toMeters(final double meters){
            return meters;
        }
    },
    MILES{
        @Override
        public double toMiles(final double miles){
            return miles;
        }

        @Override
        public double toMeters(final double miles){
            return miles / 0.00062137D;
        }
    };

    public abstract double toMiles(double unit);
    public abstract double toMeters(double unit);
}
```

**Недостатки использования `enum`**

- К ним не применимы операторы >, <, >=, <=. Следовательно `enum` не
  стоит применять в списке последовательных данных.
- `enum` также требует больше памяти для хранения чем обычная
  константа.

**`IntDef` и `StringDef` в Android**

Google [*не рекомендует*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hzs6OBcvNQE) использовать `enum` в Android приложениях из-за того что это требует больше памяти. Вместо этого для Android можно использовать [`IntDef` и `StringDef`](https://noobcoderblog.wordpress.com/2015/04/12/java-enum-and-android-intdefstringdef-annotation/) которые позволяют ограничивать пространство значений для обычных констант. Следовательно, вы получаете главное преимущество `enum` не теряя в использовании памяти. Это практика повсеместно используется в стандартных классах Android:

```
/** @hide */
@IntDef({VISIBLE, INVISIBLE, GONE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Visibility {}

/**
 * This view is visible.
 * Use with {@link #setVisibility} and <a href="#attr_android:visibility">{@code
 * android:visibility}.
 */
public static final int VISIBLE = 0x00000000;

/**
 * This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.
 * Use with {@link #setVisibility} and <a href="#attr_android:visibility">{@code
 * android:visibility}.
 */
public static final int INVISIBLE = 0x00000004;

/**
 * This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout
 * purposes. Use with {@link #setVisibility} and <a href="#attr_android:visibility">{@code
 * android:visibility}.
 */
public static final int GONE = 0x00000008;
```

В принимающем методе используется специальная аннотация:

```
public void setVisibility(@Visibility int visibility) {
    setFlags(visibility, VISIBILITY_MASK);
    if (mBackground != null) mBackground.setVisible(visibility == VISIBLE, false);
}
```

В таком случае вы не сможете использовать другую константу для этого метода:

```
view.setVisibility(456);//Error: Must be one of: View.VISIBLE, View.INVISIBLE, View.GONE
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, особенно за ссылку на видео. Кольт очень хорошо доказал, что лучше пренебречь данным классом. Благодарю вас.

Answer (score 12):

**Перечисления** (`Enum`) удобно использовать для представления множества взаимоисключающих состояний.

Пример **Перечисления** кодов сообщения:

```
enum MessageCode
{
    // Установка однозначного соответствия 
    // между элементом перечисления и целочисленным значением.
    UNKNOWN(0),

    TOAST(1),
    MESSAGE(2);

    private final int id;

    MessageCode(int code)
    {
        id = code;
    }

    // Метод получения целочисленного значения,
    // соответствующего выбранному элементу Перечисления (Enum)
    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    // Метод получения элемента Перечисления (Enum),
    // соответствующего переданному целочисленному значению
    public static MessageCode fromId(int code)
    {
        MessageCode[] list = MessageCode.values();

        if (code >= 0 && code < list.length)
            return list[code];
        else
            return MessageCode.UNKNOWN;
    }
}
```

Пример анализа сообщений:

```
private Messenger chatUIThreadMessenger = new Messenger(new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        String str;
        switch (MessageCode.fromId(msg.what))
        {
        // Доступ к выводу Toast'ов для Thread'ов прослушивающих Socket'ы
        case TOAST:
            str = (String) msg.obj;
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        // Вывод сообщений в лог чата
        case MESSAGE:
            str = (String) msg.obj;
            messages.add(str);
            messagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewChat);
            listView.smoothScrollToPosition(messagesAdapter.getCount() - 1);
            break;
        // Исключительная ситуация
        case UNKNOWN:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Messenger: неопределённый тип сообщения!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        default:
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Использование `enum` вместо констант полезно, например, когда вы хотите ограничить возможное множество значений аргумента к-л метода. Если использовать к-л константу (`int` или `String`, например), и метод, который должен её принимать будет иметь соответствующий тип аргумента, то ничто вам не помешает передать туда что-то помимо констант. Если же вы используете `enum` то передать что-то кроме `enum` у вас не получится.

Answer (score 2):

`Enum` можно использовать как реализацию паттерна [**Singleton**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

*Преимущества*:

1. Сериализация из коробки
2. Потокобезопасность из коробки
3. Возможность использования EnumSet, EnumMap и т.д
4. Поддержка switch

*Недостатки*

1. Не ленивая инициализация

По мнению [Joshua Bloch](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%85,_%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83%D0%B0)’а это лучший способ реализации шаблона

```
public enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;
}
```